# How to open a new web browser window in a tab control vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am working on a project that includes web browser functionality, but the problem is when a javascript command creates a new tab/new window, it opens in a new IE window.

(Please note: I am **NOT** talking about clicking a link to make a new window, its in the *javascript*)

The code I have creates the new tab and a new web browser, but it does not load the web page. How would I do so?

```
 Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
    Dim wb As New WebBrowser
    Label3.Text = "Flagged New Window"
    'make tab control page
    e.Cancel = True
    Dim myTabPage As New TabPage()
    myTabPage.Text = "New Page" & (TabControl1.TabPages.Count + 1)
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage)
    '
    Label3.Text = "Created Tab Control"

    'insert new web browser control into the new page
    Label3.Text = "Inserted web browser control"
    'suppress errors
    'WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True;
    Label3.Text = "Suppressed Errors"
    'Get page
    myTabPage.Controls.Add(wb)
    wb.Navigate(sender.Url)
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not clear...You should read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  You also have e.Cancel = True so the method will be canceled

Comment: Basically the javascript of a web page spawns a new window, and I need to handle that in my code. The e.cancel cancels IE opening.

Comment: if that is the case then in your JavaScript use onClick= windows.external.VBNetmethod()